# Modular Polynomial Arithmetic in Schoof's Algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I've been trying to implement Schoof's Algorithm, and I understand it except for one part.

Near the bottom of page 7 of this paper is where my issue is: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~musiker/schoof.pdf

When we check $x' - x_\overline{t}^q \equiv 0$ (mod $\psi_l$), how does this make sense? The left side is a rational function, while the modulo is a polynomial. Are we only checking the numerator? If not, how do you take rational functions modulo a polynomial? Thank you!

Comment: And if you have $\frac 3 2 - \frac 1 4$, would you say it's divisible by 2? By 5?

Comment: Well, obviously not, but how does that apply here? The statement has to be true in some cases for the algorithm to work.

Comment: One of the sensible definitions is that a number $p/q$ is divisible by integer $n$, if $p/q = 0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_n$. (so first compute the modular inverse of $q$ and multiply it by $p$). Again, I'm not sure if it's the right definition here.

Comment: I think this is equality in the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(l,\psi_l(x,y))= (R^\times)^{-1} R$ : $\psi_l(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and $x' - x_\overline{t}^q = \frac{u(x,y)}{v(x,y)}$ where $u(x,y),v(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

If there exists $w(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $v(x,y)w(x,y) \equiv  1 \bmod (l,\psi_l(x,y))$ then we say $\frac{u(x,y)}{v(x,y)} \equiv w(x,y)u(x,y) \bmod (l,\psi_l(x,y))$. In that case $\frac{u(x,y)}{v(x,y)} \equiv 0 \bmod (l,\psi_l(x,y))$ iff $u(x,y)\equiv 0 \bmod (l,\psi_l(x,y))$ @enedil

Comment: Thank you for your response. From what I understand, you're saying that $\psi_l$ divides $x' - x_\overline{t}^q$ if and only if its numerator is divisible by $\psi_l$? Thank you once again. I'm a freshman in high school, so I want some clarification.